# .Net Single Digit Type

Tags: .net

Is there a data type I can use to store a single digit, but nothing else. i.e. one of 0 - 9 and nothing else.

I know I could use `short`, `int` or `long`, but it's for the design of an api and I want to be clear that the user should only give me a single digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) type.

```
public enum Digit
{
    Zero, 
    One,
    Two,
    Three, 
    Four, 
    Five, 
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight, 
    Nine
}
```

Benefits:

1. Easily understood.
2. Directly convertible to and from its underlying type

Disadvantage:

1. Theoretically possible to create instances that don't belong in the [0 - 9] range since an enum instance can take any value of the underlying type.

Comment: I'd thought about that, I was just hoping that there would be a predefined type that my google-fu was failing to find.

Comment: if anything, it should be `public enum Digit : byte`, but important: enums are not validated. You can have (fully slid, both at compile and run-time): `Digit digit = (Digit)42;` - not a show-stopper, necessarily - I actually like this idea

Comment: @Marc: I mentioned the validation bit. About using `byte` as the underlying type: sure, if space were a concern.

Comment: @Ani you did in the edit :p my comment was on the original version. Again, I do like this approach.

Comment: @Marc: One point: "Use type Int32 as the underlying type of an enum unless either of the following is true:
The enum represents flags and there are currently more than 32 flags, or the enum might grow to have many flags in the future.
The type needs to be different from int for backward compatibility."         http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you could go.

- Create your own value type
- Use an enum - seems silly to enum 0 through 9 though
- Just use a short and throw an exception if it's too large...

I think that latter would be the clearest in terms of an API. I would only created a new type if it's going to be used frequently throughout a large and complex API.

```
using System;
public class MyClass {
    public static void Main() {
        var test = new ApiClass();
        test.MyNum = 0; // OK
        test.MyNum = 1; // OK
        test.MyNum = 9; // OK

        test.MyNum = 10; // exception
        test.MyNum = -1; // exception
    }   
}

public class ApiClass {
    private short _myNum;
    public short MyNum {
        get {
            return _myNum;
        }
        set {
            if (value < 0 || value > 9)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value must be between 0 and 9!");

            _myNum = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
struct SingleDigit
{
    readonly byte singleDigit;

    public SingleDigit() 
    {
        singleDigit = 0;
    }

    public SingleDigit(byte value)
    {
        // NOTE: it's not a good practice to throw in a ctor
        if(value < 0 || value > 9)
            throw new ArgumenException();

        singleDigit = value;
    }

    // explicit byte to digit conversion operator
    public static explicit operator SingleDigit(byte b)  
    {
        Digit d = new SingleDigit(b);  // explicit conversion
        return d;
    }

    // explicit byte to digit conversion operator
    public static explicit operator SingleDigit(int b)  
    {
        Digit d = new SingleDigit((byte) b);  // explicit conversion
        return d;
    }

    // implicit digit to byte conversion operator
    public static implicit operator byte(SingleDigit digit)  
    {
        return digit.singleDigit;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return singleDigit.ToString();
    }

}
```

I added implicit (for lossless conversion) and explicit casting operators so you can use it as if it is a normal type, like so:

```
// explicit (possible loss)
SingleDigit digit = (SingleDigit) 9;

// implicit conversion (lossless)
int convertedDigit = digit;
```

Advantages:

- Simple to use
- Works and feels as any other basic type like byte, char, int
- Can easily be expanded with `IConverter` etc to behave more like standard types

Disadvantages:

- Slightly more work to build and maintain than just an enum
- Might be harder to make it as strong and stable as existing types

Comment: Please replace the setter with a parameterized constructor.

Comment: I believe @CodeInChaos is (quite rightly) objecting that there is no reason for this to be mutable - and harmful in being mutable.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I was still typing and editing while you were commenting (it's there now). And @Marc is probably right it shouldn't be mutable, but that's up to the user. It's easy enough to remove the `.Value`. Likewise, a lot more is missing (like class cast exceptions).

Comment: There are several issues remaining: 1) the setter 2) the implicit cast to `int` is superfluous 3) You can't have a custom default constructor 4) I'd mark the field `readonly` 5) You're using both `Digit` and `SingleDigit` as class name.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: thanks for all the pointers. That's what happens if you code "by heart". Clearly need my editor ;). Tried to fix some of your mentioned issues, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no .Net type available with that capability.  It's fairly straight forward to create though

```
public sealed class OneDigit {  
  public static readonly OneDigit One = new OneDigit(1);
  public static readonly OneDigit Two = new OneDigit(2);
  public static readonly OneDigit Three = new OneDigit(3);
  public static readonly OneDigit Four = new OneDigit(4);
  public static readonly OneDigit Five = new OneDigit(5);
  public static readonly OneDigit Six = new OneDigit(6);
  public static readonly OneDigit Seven = new OneDigit(7);  
  public static readonly OneDigit Eight = new OneDigit(8);
  public static readonly OneDigit Nine = new OneDigit(9);

  private readonly int _value;
  public int Value {
    get { return _value; }
  }

  private OneDigit(int value) {
    _value = value;
  }

  public static bool TryCreate(int value, out OneDigit digit) {
    if (value >=0 && value <= 9) {
      digit = new OneDigit(value);
      return true;
    }
    digit = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just go with an appropriate parameter/member name, and validate it as usual. IMO defining a custom type is over-engineering.

But if you want to go the custom type route, I'd define the struct as follows:

```
public struct DecimalDigit
{
    readonly byte _value;

    public DecimalDigit(int value)
    {
        if(value<0||value>9)
            throw new ArgumentException("value", "value must be between 0 and 9");
        _value = (byte)value;
    }

    public byte Value 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator DecimalDigit(int i)  
    {
        return new DecimalDigit(i);
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(DecimalDigit digit)  
    {
        return digit.Value;
    }
}
```

Plus a few interface implementations(`IEquatable<Digit>`, `IComparer<Digit>`, `IConvertible`), equality comparison, `ToString()`,... which I omitted here. With those it becomes quite a bit of code for little gain.